# How can I deserialize a bincode serialised data into something like serde_json::Value?

Tags: json, rust, serde, bincode

I have a IPC implementation where a process serializes a struct using [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode)

On the other end, I'm receiving it and lets say this process is not aware of the struct it is receiving,
Here, I want to do something like

```rust
let parsed: Result<serde_json::Value, serde_json::Error> = serde_json::from_str(json_str);
```

but with bincode, is it possible?

I tried doing

```rust
let deser = bincode::deserialize::<serde_json::Value>(msg.bytes()))?;
```

But it throws error

```
Error: Bincode does not support the serde::Deserializer::deserialize_any method
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't because the bincode deserializer has to be informed about the type to expect, but `serde_json::Value` relies on the deserializer to tell it what type is next. Both requirements contradict each other.
That's also expressed in the [documentation of `deserialize_any`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.Deserializer.html#tymethod.deserialize_any):

> When implementing `Deserialize`, you should avoid relying on `Deserializer::deserialize_any` unless you need to be told by the `Deserializer` what type is in the input. Know that relying on `Deserializer::deserialize_any` means your data type will be able to deserialize from self-describing formats only, ruling out Postcard and many others.

`bincode` is one of those formats that do *not* describe itself.